# Converting XML to HTML with good formatting

Tags: php, html, xml

I succeed at converting a XML file into a HTML one, but the output file is horrible. I would like a HTML file with the structure of the XML file (including clickable links).

My code :

```
public function SitemapHTML() {
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
    $dom->load('sitemap.xml');

    $data = $dom->getElementsByTagName('loc');

    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    echo '<HTML>';
    echo '<HEAD>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';
    echo '</HEAD>';
    echo '<BODY>';
    echo ("<table>");

    foreach ($data as $node)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        $thisurl = $node->textContent;
        echo ("<td>" .
            '<a href="' . $thisurl . '">' . $thisurl . '</a>' .
            "</td>");
        echo '</tr>';

    }
    echo ("<table>");
    echo '</BODY>';
    echo '</HTML>';
    $dom->saveHTMLFile('ok.html');

}
```

HTML output file : [image: Not what I want]

I have looked all over google and stackoverflow. Tried many things, but nothing.

I would like a HTML file that has the structure of a common XML sitemap file.

Comment: The table is not closed properly. You have a second `<table>` tag instead of `</table>`.

Comment: Just to be clear, XML is a generic format for storing just about any kind of data. So a tool for formatting "an XML file" would have to be incredibly complex; it sounds like what you're looking at is _a particular format of XML file_, but you don't actually show a sample input. As for "the format is horrible", you can write out whatever format you want; learn some basic HTML and CSS and go nuts.

Comment: XML can be styled with CSS or transformed with XSLT.